# 'Index out of range using input dim 0' Error while using ' tf.while_loop '

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

**I am facing this issue while creating a decoder using tf.while_loop**

```
train_decoder = tf.while_loop(self.coarse_decoder_condition, self.coarse_decoder_function,
[self.iter_decoder_c, tf.zeros([1,self.c_dec_size]), tf.ones([self.c_dec_size])] ,\
shape_invariants=[self.iter_decoder_c.get_shape(),\
tf.TensorShape([None,self.c_dec_size]),\
tf.TensorShape([self.c_dec_size]) ] )
```

**here is what comes up in the cmd**

```

```
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2816, in while_loop
    result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2640, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2576, in _BuildLoop
    c = ops.convert_to_tensor(pred(*packed_vars))

  File "C:\Users\HP\Music\Final\nn.py", line 200, in coarse_decoder_condition
    return it[0] < self.oplen_c[0]

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 538, in _SliceHelper
    name=name)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 706, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 5429, in strided_slice
    name=name)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_he
lper
    op_def=op_def)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2958, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2209, in set_shapes_for_outputs

    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2159, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py", line 627, in call_cpp_shap
e_fn
    require_shape_fn)

  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py", line 691, in _call_cpp_sha
pe_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0 dims for 'Coarse_Decoder/while/strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shape
s: [], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[3] = <1>.
```

```

Essentially what is happening is that the while_loop => buildloop => _SliceHelper

the _sliceHelper chooses strided_slice op(which requires 4 args instead of 3) instead of just slice op

This is causing me to get an error while passing 3 args , which is what my requirement is.

A similar issue highlighted [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/817)

I can't manually choose slice() over strided_slice()

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you ever find the answer?